# How to compare data in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read back the data in Firebase which is medical = "Diabetes" which key in by the user.If this user has the medical history of diabetes will display something not allow the user to buy. Anyone can teach me how to write this condition in the android studio?

[Firebase data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ure38.png)

```
public class Pain_and_Fever extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button btnSubmit, btnCancel;
private String userID;
Query query;


//add Firebase Database stuff
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private DatabaseReference myRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pain_and__fever);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttnsubmit);
    btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttncancel);


    //declare the database reference object. This is what we use to access the database.
    //NOTE: Unless you are signed in, this will not be useable.
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userID = user.getUid();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

   query = myRef.orderByChild("medical").equalTo("Diabetes");

}

     private void submit(){
         query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                     for (DataSnapshot issue : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                         UserInformation uInfo = issue.getValue(UserInformation.class);
                         if (uInfo.getMedical().equals("Diabetes")){
                             startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Medicine.class));

                         }else{
                             myRef.child("Medicines").child("Pain and Fever").child(userID).setValue("Acetaminophen");
                             startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Medicine.class));
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

             }
         });

         }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == btnSubmit){
            submit();
        }
        if (view == btnCancel){
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Medicine.class));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: use query for that

Comment: Query query = reference.child("Users").orderByChild("id");  using this?

Comment: see my answer and change it as per your requirement

Comment: Can you help me to check my code? Because when i click my submit button it's not functioning.

Comment: query = myRef.orderByChild("medical").equalTo("Diabetes"); 

put this inside submit method

Comment: same the submit button can't function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, this works for me

```
 Query chatRoomsQuery = mFirebaseDatabase.orderByChild("medical").equalTo("your value");


                        chatRoomsQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                    // dataSnapshot is the "issue" node with all children with id 0

                                    search_list=new ArrayList<SearchModel>();
                                    for (DataSnapshot issue : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                        // do something with the individual "issues"
                                        UserRegisterModel mModel = issue.getValue(UserRegisterModel.class);
                                        if(mModel.getArea().equals(sel_area))

                                    hidepDialog();

                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }
```